# Ban [programming] as a tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

Any post not about programming should go, after all, so it adds no information.

I noticed five such tags in the 10k tools today. Four were completely spurious and have been removed. One appears to have been a mis-tag of [parallel-programming].

---

**Edit**: As of 24 August [programming] has made a comeback. Off to fix it, again.

Comment: I've removed the tag of the last question on the site. So it wont be suggested any more when entering tags. It will take someone with 1500+ rep to recreate it and they should know better

Comment: @ChrisF I thought I got them all. Maybe I missed one, or it was new, or maybe there is a race condition in the caching. Any way, thanks.

Comment: I did wonder why one showed up, anyway all gone now and should be harder to recreate

Comment: Still should be banned though

Comment: @Chris: IIRC, once a tag exists in the system, even if there are no questions associated with it, *any* user can use the tag on a question, even though it doesn't show up in the list. The 1500 rep threshold only applies for actual new tags that don't yet exist in the system.

Comment: @Jon - but with it not showing on the list there's a reduced chance it will show up again quite as quickly.

Comment: @Chris: Although it's tough to say how often a user would just randomly type "parallel programming" in the tags box without even checking the autocomplete, I do agree with you.

Comment: @jon only until the cleanup processes run at around 00:00 UTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, it's banned.

Comment: Is there any chance that this is what's affecting `[functional-programming]`, `[parallel-programming]`, and `[pair-programming]`? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62224/is-functional-programming-now-considered-a-meta-tag

Comment: ...but a positive side-effect is that we can't add the `[not-programming-related]` tag anymore either.  :)

Comment: @bill I changed the rule to be more restrictive -- my bad