# Is "functional-programming" now considered a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

I just tried to retag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564938/function-programming-and-mock-objects) with the `functional-programming` tag, since it clearly relates to that. Imagine my surprise to be told that

> sorry, the 'functional-programming' tag is not allowed.

Does this mean that `functional-programming` is now considered a banned meta-tag? Surely not - this is a style of programming, not a style of question.

Comment: Surely not. There are 1050 questions tagged [functional-programming] and 3185 questions tagged [oop]. [design-patterns] is still a valid tag, as is [oop]

Comment: Hmm..possibly an overly strong reaction [feedback
Ban programming as a tag on Stack Overflow
](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61822/ban-programming-as-a-tag-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: Confirmed, I can't retag `[functional]` -> `[functional-programming]`.  I wonder if `[*programming]` or its equivalent was banned [when this was implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61822/ban-programming-as-a-tag-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: @dmckee: Agree with banning [programming], but not [functional-programming].

Comment: What about [parallel-programming]? Is that banned too?

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, it looks like `[parallel-programming]` is banned as well.

Comment: As is `[pair-programming]`

Comment: @Bill: `[ajsskdfhprogramming]` and `[programmingksdjfhskjfh]` also aren't allowed, so it's definitely a match for `*programming*`.

Comment: [Jeff made the rule more restrictive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61822/ban-programming-as-a-tag-on-stack-overflow/62181#62181), so we're back in business.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would flag your question for moderator attention and see if they can remove [functional-programming] from the blacklist.  [functional-programming] does not meet [Jeff's criteria](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for a meta-tag.

Comment: Some of these do meet one criterion for a meta-tag:  meaning different things to different people.  This would be especially true for [object-oriented-programming], of course.