# Strip banned tags, like [programming], when migrating

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, migration

The [banned-on-SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61822) and repeatedly [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/please-remove-the-programming-tag) tag [programming](/questions/tagged/programming) reappeared after [a question from Web Apps SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095770) was migrated to SO.

As of a few minutes ago, there were only six questions with the tag, so I just retagged them, and the [programming](/questions/tagged/programming) tag should thus disappear again after batch processing tonight.

If an admin is bored, I propose adding an enhancement to the migration process that strips questions of tags banned on the target site, and/or notifies the user(s) migrating the question of the conflict.

Comment: That was migrated a while back

Comment: I don't understand your point.  Does the current migration process already handle this?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Migration does strip tags, you can read up on it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78720/blacklisted-tags-on-migrated-questions-prevent-users-from-suggesting-edits/78722#78722).

Comment: Thank you for the info.  My search-fu failed when I was posting this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of February 2011, [the migration system strips tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78720/blacklisted-tags-on-migrated-questions-prevent-users-from-suggesting-edits/78722#78722). It specifically removes tags which are not present on the target site. As by definition, blacklisted tags will not exist, any blacklisted tags will be stripped on migration.

Your example, as pointed out by [random](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) in the comments, was migrated prior to the instantiation of this new system.